# Nano Syntax Highlighting Colors

Tags: colors, nano

Where can I find a complete list of supported colors used in syntax highlighting for the GNU Nano text editor? I've looked through the man pages, and it gave the syntax for defining syntax coloring, but didn't provide a color reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[man nanorc(5):](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nanorc)

> **color fgcolor,bgcolor regex**
>
> For the currently defined syntax,
> display all expressions matching the extended regular expression regex
> with foreground color fgcolor and background color bgcolor, at least
> one of which must be specified. Legal colors for foreground and
> background color are: **white, black, red, blue, green, yellow, magenta,
> and cyan**. You may use the *prefix* **"bright"** to force a stronger color
> highlight for the foreground. If your terminal supports transparency,
> not specifying a bgcolor tells nano to attempt to use a transparent
> background.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I compared this to the one I found, and it didn't include anything after the first sentence. (It did specify that it was a summary though)

Answer (score 0):

The one Symin shared is great, it meets basic requirements for syntax highlighting. But in more complex case like JSON or Python, you may want a better detail document:

- https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html
  (This is for version 5 and later)

And here is the standard color list for terminal:

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

But my experience said that nano also support `orange` as well.